# feature selection using varimp

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

```
# ensure results are repeatable
set.seed(7)
# load the library
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
# load the dataset
data(liver)
# prepare training scheme
control1 <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
# train the model
liver.imputed <- rfImpute(datset2 ~ ., Liver12)

liver.imputed <- as.data.frame(liver.imputed)

str(liver.imputed)

model <- train(Dataset~., data=liver.imputed, method="lvq", preProcess="scale", trControl=control)

# estimate variable importance

importance <- varImp(model, scale=FALSE)
# summarize importance

print(importance)
# plot importance
plot(importance)
```

getting this error
Please if someone can look into it I am doing feature selection by using varimp but when I am running my model its is showing me the below error

**Error: wrong model type for regression**

Comment: in the model statement the outcome column is datset2

Comment: where does the `liver` data come from, which package?

Comment: it is manually created dataset i can upload file if you want it

Comment: It may be useful to reproduce the error

Comment: could you tell me how I can upload dataste .CSV file here

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
y <-read.csv ("file.csv", header = T, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=F, colClasses=c("Dataset"="character"))
```